# Plotting metaMDS results: How do I get a horizontal plot with a one-dimensional MDS?

Tags: r, plot, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm making a one-dimensional rescaling using the `metaMDS` function from the `vegan` package as follows:

```
mydata <- data.frame(X = sample(1:50), Y = sample(1:50), Z = sample(1:50))
mds <- metaMDS(mydata, distance="euclidian", autotransform=FALSE, k=1)
```

(This example has just random data, and may not converge, but since the point here is the visualisation, it doesn't matter.)

When I plot this `(plot(mds))`, I get a nice vertical axis with the original data points and the data dimensions. However, I would like to have the plot rotated so that the axis is horizontal but the labels are still oriented to be vertically readable.

How can I plot a one-dimensional MDS result from metaMDS as a horizontal figure?

Comment: I don't think that's currently possible "out of the box".

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: I think you'll have to custumize `linestack()` for your needs.

Comment: agstudy: edited the post to provide some data. EDi: any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Where do you need that graph? If you need it in an external application, can you rotate the graph? Implementing this behaviour is not too difficult, but it is boring and adds a large number of dull lines of code. I considered doing this once, but I lost my motivation. Contributions to vegan are appreciated and will be incorporated crediting the author.